# .NET Web Application Template Gallery

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, templates

Does anyone know of a css-template gallery for .NET web application projects? I mean a collection of css-templates that works with the standard .NET 4 web application project. There is a gallery like that for MVC here:

http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

But I can't find anything similar for .NET web application projects. I'm just looking for some simple templates that I can easily drop into a new project because I'm tired of the standard blue in blue template that visual studio uses out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Your best be might be to find some project that is dedicated to developing additional default Asp.net VS 2010 templates.

[This is one such project](http://codesmartnothard.com/CategoryView,category,CSS.aspx) I'm sure there are many other/better ones in various places but this is certainly a start.